# How to add stencils in visio file dynamically (C#)

Tags: c#, interop, visio

I have One Visio document and one Stencil(.vss) file.                               Requirement:  Add this stencil file inside the Visio document dynamically.

```
    private static void InsertStencilsToVisio()
    {           
        string fileName = @"C:\Visio Files\TestVisio.vdw";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            visioDocument = visioApplication.Documents.Open(fileName);
            visioPage = visioApplication.Window.Application.ActivePage;
            eswStencilDocument = visioPage.Application.Documents["eswstencil.vss"];
            CreateShapes();
        }
    }
```

Can I use VisOpenSaveArgs? to crack this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use visOpenRO + visOpenDocked:

```
visioDocument = visioApplication.Documents.Open(fileName);

visioApplication.Documents.OpenEx("eswstencil.vss", 
    (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRO|(short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
```

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Thanks for your suggestion.  I had experimented this already. (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenRO:  Will open the stencil in read-only mode only. In this case it just open a new stencil window along with a visio document, which leads to additional overhead while saving.  Exact one for adding a stencil to  visio file is (short)VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it by the myself.  In this I had opened Visio document  and docked the stencils to the visio dynamically while opening it. Later the document get saved with stencil.

```
   private static void InsertStencilsToVisio()
   {   visioApplication = new Application();
        string fileName = @"C:\siva\CreateGen1Visio\pd-m-0001_1.11.vdw";
        string stencilFileName = @"C:\siva\CreateGen1Visio\eswstencil.vss";

        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                visioDocument = visioApplication.Documents.OpenEx(fileName, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDontList);
                visioPage = visioDocument.Application.ActivePage;
                visioPage.Application.Documents.OpenEx(stencilFileName, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);
                visioDocument.SaveAsEx(fileName, (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.VisOpenSaveArgs.visSaveAsWS);
            }
        }
   }
```